QGIS: The grid coordinates are in the correct format but wrong accuracy wise. How do I fix this?
I am not a map expert what so ever and need help fixing the grid numbers on a this Antarctic map.
**The grids should be displaying a longitude that covers where my data points (sites) are sitting: Longitude of ~166°26'17"E-166°27'11"E and  latitude of ~77°12'44"S-77°13'04"S. Instead the grid has listed coordinates with a latitude of 30°0'0.000"S-50°0'0.000"N and a longitude of 0°0'0.000"S-100°0'0.000"E. **

I thought that I could fix it by changing the CRS the grid uses but encountered more problems.The grid CRS is set to "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84". If I change the grid CRS to "EPSG:3031 Antarctic Polar Stereographic (like project CRS)" or "use map CRS" the grid is still displaying inaccurate lat and long with northern coordinates. If I set the contour, coastline, or project CRS to something else they either appear like a flat earth map/distorted or disapear all together. I think I have tried all of the CRS combinations at this so maybe this is a grid setting issue. I attached screenshots of the grid settings.

Additional Details:
There isn't a base map set for this map with the grid issue. In this case I used the coastline (nz-ross-dependency-coastline...) to draw out the map and then added contour (nz-ross-dependency-contours...) to show land elevation.
The data points were imported with the CRS set as "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84". The project CRS is "WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic EPSG:3031". The contour and coastline layer CRS are set to "EPSG:5479 - RSRGD2000 / MSLC2000".

try changing the units from millimetres to map units

I have changed the units from millimetres to map units and the grid disapeared completely (including the inferior tick marks). So it just cancels out the entire grid.

I FIXED ITTTTTT!!!! I changed the grid interval to "fit segment width" and the correct coordinates appear. Both latitude and longitude appeared on the left and right frame so I also had to change the Left division settings to "Latitude/Y only" and Top divisions to "Longitude/X only". The only problem I have now is when I set the minimum and maximum for intervals the top grid appears overcrowded. If I change the maximum interval to a higher number the top isn't crowded but the left grid only has 1 coordinate displayed. Is there a way to have different intervals for the left vs. the top grid?

I fixed the overcrowding issue by making 2 seperate grids. One for the latitude and 1 for the longitude. That way they have different min and max intervals.
